# ServiceStack Returned Date Zone

Tags: date, format, servicestack

I'm not sure how\where to deal with this to be honest...

So when I debug my service the value set to return in VS is 11/25/2015 11:59:59

The JSON returned on the client however shows it at 
http://dojo.telerik.com/@steve@sitefinitysteve.com/oZaPe
(or Tue Jan 26 2016 04:59:59 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time))

Is there a way to tell servicestack to always return -5 instead of needing to hunt down every date object in the entire system to convert or something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ServiceStack - Is there a way to force all serialized Dates to use a specific DateTimeKind?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19694475/servicestack-is-there-a-way-to-force-all-serialized-dates-to-use-a-specific-da)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override how DateTime's are serialized by assinging: `JsConfig<DateTime>.SerializeFn` - see this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19708432/85785) or these [Custom DateTime tests](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/6e92c5bbb08937b85f701e981ba4519138016ac6/tests/ServiceStack.Text.Tests/JsonTests/CustomRawSerializerTests.cs#L245) for examples.