# Customize ServiceStack v3 JsConfig based on request header

Tags: servicestack

I have an existing v3 ServiceStack implementation and I want to change the way in which the dates are serialized/deserialized. However, since there are a large number of existing external customers using this service I can't just make that change globally without breaking their mobile applications that use my services.

As a result I want to change the [`JsConfig<DateTime>.SerializeFn`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19694475/servicestack-is-there-a-way-to-force-all-serialized-dates-to-use-a-specific-da) but only when a particular request header is identified.

How would I go about this per request, rather than at the application level?